# Microsoft visual studio 2015 has stopped working and restating continuously.

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have been working on visual studio 2015 on windows 10 since 6 months,it has no crashes till yesterday,when i opened today it started showing `Micro soft Visual Studio has stopped working` and within no to again showing  `Micro soft Visual Studio is restarting...` it is happening for all projects not only for the single project which i am currently working,Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried running a Repair with the Update Manager?

Comment: Thanks for responding @schulmaster,could you please guide me on how to do that.

Comment: The easiest way is to open the Control Panel, go to Add/Remove Programs, and click on Visual Studio 2015. This will invoke the manager, which will present you with a Modify, Repair, or Remove set of options. Select Repair. Make sure you have an active internet connection, NO IDEs open, and about 30min to spare.

Comment: Thank you for the help@schulmaster,i tried the way and i got `a setup package is either damaged or missing`, do i need to skip packages or download packages.

Comment: At that point, it is at your own risk that you try a repair, bc there is clearly a more serious issue with your installation. If you have the time, I'd recommended a remove/reinstall, but you can always try to download what VS thinks is missing/required

Comment: Thank you soo much for responding @schulmaster ,i ,i installed vs 2017 and iam not getting that error anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most applications, if you cannot get them to work, as long as all your stuff is saved, just reinstall. (if all else fails)
This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you Michael,i installed vs 2017 and iam not getting that error anymore.

Comment: Can you please give me credit (upvote). My account has been banned because although i'm answering questions correctly sometimes, they don't get upvoted because they're usually obvious answers